# $scope.$on event triggers multiple times

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What I want to do is to broadcast a message from MyCtrl2 to MyCtrl2, and that works fine. However I have a directive that runs in multiple places, and that directive needs the attribute value in the markup and a scope variable from MyCtrl1. So one solution I found was to add 'controller: "MyCtrl1"' in the directive itself to access the scope, however this causes the broadcast message event to trigger multiple times in MyCtrl1.

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl1">
    Breadcast message: {{ message }}
    <br /><br />
    <div my-directive="test1"></div>
    <div my-directive="test2"></div>
</div>

<div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">
    <input type="text" name="message" ng-model="message" />
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="doBroadcast()">Broadcast</button>

    <br >
    <div my-directive="test3"></div>
    <div my-directive="test4"></div>
</div>



var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        controller: 'MyCtrl1', 
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            element.html(attrs.myDirective + ' - ' + scope.variable);
        }
    };
});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl1', function($scope) {

    $scope.variable = "MyCtrl1 Variable";

    $scope.$on('message', function ($event, message) {
        console.log("message recieved");
        $scope.message = message;
    });

});

myApp.controller('MyCtrl2', function($scope, $rootScope) {

    $scope.doBroadcast = function() {
        console.log('broadcast message');
        $rootScope.$broadcast('message', $scope.message);
    }

});
```

Is there a better way to MyCtrl1 scope in the directive without $events firing?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oligustafsson/j11y3xxp/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directive's controller is MyCtrl1, so multiple controller object is generated on runtime and every controller catches the message.
Delete `controller: 'MyCtrl1',` line or use another controller for the directive.

**UPDATE:**
A service may be used to share data between controllers. See updated version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zunehfaa/

Comment: Right, but how can i get MyCtrl1 scope in the directive?

Comment: You can use a service to share data between controllers. See my updated answer, please.

Comment: Perfect, that fits the bill. Thank you for the enlightenment :-)